# Copying songs on to iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes, music

I have music purchased online, but I do not have my phone synced to iTunes.  How do I put my songs into the phone?

I have tried using DropBox, but the song has to be downloaded every time!

Comment: iTunes is the 'master' the phone merely the 'slave'... so you start from iTunes & sync **to** the phone, not the other way round.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to play music on your iPhone using the Music.app and you haven't purchased the music on the iTunes Music Store (iTMS), you have to sync your iPhone and the music with iTunes first.

### Play music with the Music.app

You can play music with the Music.app if one of the following conditions are true:

- You have **purchased the song on the iTMS**
- you have subscribed to **iTunes Match** and your preferred song is available
- you have **added the song to your iTunes** library on your computer and **synced your iPhone** with the same iTunes library (enable "sync music")
- you have subscribed to **iTunes Match**, added the song in iTunes on your computer and turned on iTunes Match on your iPhone

Please let me know if this answers your question.

---

edit:

Alternative method

### Play music on iPhones/iOS with alternative music players

You can download and play purchased music stored in your Dropbox if the following conditions are true:

- The **songs have no DRM** applied (encrypted audio containers like "m4p")
- you have downloaded an [**alternative music player** from the App Store](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:itunes.apple.com%20dropbox%20music)
- you have already **downloaded the song** or a data connection to download it

Comment: I knew there was a reason I just have all my music in iTunes & just duped to the phone... solid data, backed up, no online versions. I know what's mine & where it lives. [+1 anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's a little weird for copying songs into an iPhone, but it is possible, and I have done it many times.

1. Connect the device through USB to the computer.
2. Open up iTunes
3. Download and drag the online music into iTunes
4. Click and hold the album or song until the "Playlists" menu comes up.
5. You will see a device called "[name] iPhone"
6. Drag the music onto the device until a menu opens up with things like "Music", etc.
7. Drag it into the music section.

Comment: I've been using iTunes for 16 years & don't recognise that as a working method

Comment: Worked for me though

Comment: @Tetsujin BTW it is a Windows thing